# jq filtering based on conditions

Tags: jq

How can I use `jq` to do filtering based on certain conditions?

Using the example from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/#result2 for e.g., say I want to filter the results by

- `.commit.author.date>=2016`, and
- `.commit.comment_count>=1`

All the items not satisfying such criteria will not show up in the end result.

What's the proper `jq` expression to do that? Thx.

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you looked at the jq manual? Have you tried jqplay.org ?

Comment: @peak, yes. What do you mean? You agree that it is impossible?

Comment: @GillesQuenot, if you have spent one more second looking into https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/#result2, you will find that it is a _Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_ right there.

Comment: @xpt: so why don't put mcve here ? Expected sample input and expected output...

Comment: @GillesQuenot First, if you know `jq` well then you wouldn't ask such question -- the link I provided is the _bible_ of `jq` that people refer to and consult with _all the time_. Second, not all questions need expected sample input and expected output, you need to change your view on that. This is a conceptual question and Jeff's answer is perfect fine, without _any_ expected sample input and expected output. Third, I really don't like your down-vote because of your lack of understanding and personal biased view.

Comment: Really go read mcve link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is an array of objects that contain commit information. Since you want to filter that array, you usually will want to `map/1` that array and filter using `select/1`: `map(select(...))`. You just need to provide the condition to filter.

```
map(select(.commit | (.author.date[:4] | tonumber) >= 2016 and .comment_count >= 1))
```

The date in this particular case is a date string in iso format. I'm assuming you wanted to get the commits that were in the year 2016 and beyond. Extract the year part and compare.

```
(.author.date[:4] | tonumber) >= 2016
```

Then combine that with comparing the comment count.

Note, I projected to the commit first to minimize repetition in the filter. I could have easily left that part out.

```
map(select((.commit.author.date[:4] | tonumber) >= 2016 and .commit.comment_count >= 1))
```

Comment: This Q/A helped me find a [better Github search approach](https://medium.com/@suntong001/query-github-graphql-9a4547d33bad), Thanks Jeff.